# How can I access standard ArcMap cursors?

Tags: arcobjects, add-in

I'm writing an Add-In for ArcGIS 10 and would like to use the standard mouse cursors ArcMap uses (e.g. the info cursor and the edit cursor). I hope it is possible to just use the right reference in the add-in config file and not copy the cursor image file.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference whatever cursor you would like in the config file but you might have to copy the image to your project which is what you don't want to do.

Beyond that you can use the **[IMouseCursor.SetCursor Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0023000000rr000000)** and choose one of the 11 default cursors.

Comment: These default cursors are the system's default cursors. What I'm looking for are the ArcGIS cursors (e.g. the one used by the identify tool). There is an enum value esriControlsMousePointer.esriPointerIdentify, but how can I use this one in a add-in Tool?

Comment: Those could be icons not cursors. (Editing Tool, etc) You can find a lot of those in "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\Icons" They are in a zipped folder. I don't know of another way but to copy and use the icon/cursor you want in the config file which works for me. I also make my own cursors and that works just as well.